# JSF 2.0: How to add UIComponents and their contents to view root?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, uicomponents

I am building a custom `UIComponent` and adding elements (and other stock UIComponents) inside it. The component renders ok, however it cannot be found from the `ViewRoot`.

Let's say I have:

```
ResponseWriter writer;

@Override
public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
    writer = context.getResponseWriter();
    writer.startElement("div", this);
    writer.writeText("testing", null);
    writer.writeAttribute("id", getClientId(context) + ":testDiv", null);
}

@Override
public void encodeEnd(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
    writer.endElement("div");        
}
```

Adding that as:

```
<x:myUiComponent id="myComponent" />
```

This renders ok, however I cannot find the component or it's child div from the ViewRoot:

```
context.getViewRoot().findComponent("myComponent");  // returns null
context.getViewRoot().findComponent("myComponent:testDiv");  // returns null
findComponent("myComponent:testDiv");  // called within the custom component, throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException?
```

The same problem applies when I try to add other UIComponents as my custom component's children - they render succesfully, however cannot be found from the component tree as my custom component itself doesn't reside there.

What's the trick here to get the components into the component tree?

**Edit**: Adjusted the title to better reflect the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by a stupid mistake. As one would suppose, the added `UIComponent` *does* get automatically added to `ViewRoot`. I was, however, calling a custom `UIComponent` (the one I was talking about in the question) from inside my other custom `UIComponent` (which I din't mention because I forgot that it was there) like this:

UICodeEditor:

```
@Override
public void encodeAll(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
    UIEditPanel editor = new UIEditPanel();
    editor.encodeAll(context);
}
```

Then called this in a template like:

```
<!-- codeEditor is taghandler for UICodeEditor -->
<x:codeEditor />
```

Here, the UICodeEditor *does* get automatically added to the `ViewRoot`, however, UIEditPanel inside it does not, because I was simply calling `encodeAll(context)` and so the UIEditPanel has no way of knowing its' parent. A quick fix would be to manually set the parent of the child component:

```
editor.setParent(this);
```

Alternative approach (maybe better) would be to extend from `UIComponentBase` (as we normally do) and not manually call `encodeAll(context)` but just add the component as a child with `getChildren.add(...)` in `encodeBegin(...)` and not in `encodeAll(...)`:

```
@Override
public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
    UIEditPanel editor = new UIEditPanel();
    getChildren().add(editor);
}
```

The `getChildren().add()` internally adds the current component as parent of the children.

Considering the location of the child creation, it might be better to build them straight in the constructor and not override the `encodeXXX` methods at all, if there's no need to use `ResponseWriter` (if there is, then you need to override those). However, it is more flexible to override and manually call encoding, whatever you need.

Also note that a custom UIComponent cannot directly be an `<f:ajax render=` target, because it isn't represented by a DOM element in the DOM tree. This this the same case as with composite components, where I tend to wrap the composite component implementation into a JSF managed `panelGroup` so that the contents can be re-rendered later on.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure that `getClientId(context)` will return `myComponent`. Indeed, if your component is nested in a [`NamingContainer`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html) component, such as a `<h:form>`, his ID will be prefixed with the ID of this container.

For example, if you have the following XHTML page:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    <x:myUiComponent id="myComponent" />
```

then you will have to retrieve your component using:

```
context.getViewRoot().findComponent("myForm:myComponent");
```

---

Regarding the `context.getViewRoot().findComponent("myComponent:testDiv");` (or `context.getViewRoot().findComponent("myForm:myComponent:testDiv");`, it will return `null` because there is no such element in the **JSF components tree** on server side. The code:

```
writer.writeAttribute("id", getClientId(context) + ":testDiv", null);
```

will only set the `ID` attribute on the **HTML generated component**, ie you will have a `<div id="myForm:myComponent:testDiv">` in your HTML page sent to the browser. This `<div>` component has no existence in your JSF component tree and thus cannot be retrieved on the Java side.

Comment: Mmmm, you are right, the getClientId(context) actually returns JSF-generated ID ("j_id11" in this case). I guess one has to manually override the automatically generated ID with UIComponents (via setId()). The generated ID doesn't have prefixes in this case though, as I call my component directly from `h:body`. Anyway, how can I add my custom UIComponent so that it itself is added to the component tree (so that I can, for example, re-render it via AJAX call)? If that's not possible, how can I add sub elements inside my UIComponent so that they get added to the component tree?

Comment: Ok thanks for your input, I found the problem (see my answer). I guess this was something that even could not be seen from the question. I will try to be more careful next time!